# IEnumerable type cast

Tags: asp.net

```
{
-- 
public static IEnumerable<Datarow> Codes(string topvalue)
    {

        DataTable itemCodes = new DataTable();

        itemCodes.Columns.Add("itemId");
        itemCodes.Columns.Add("itemCode");

        itemCodes.Rows.Add(0, firstCallingCode);
        DataTable Codes = GetAllItems().Tables[0];
        foreach (DataRow item in Codes.Rows)
        {
            if (item["ItemCode"] != DBNull.Value)
            {
                itemCodes.Rows.Add(item.Field<int?>("itemId"), item.Field<string>("itemCode"));
            }
        }
        return itemCodes.AsEnumerable();d
    }
```

how can i bind it to dropdownlist: i tried this

```
ddcodes.datasource = codes.getenumerable();
ddcodes.databind();
```

when i do this i get error about typecast. i can not solve it tried a lot please help.
my method is actually this

```
public static IEnumerable"Datarow" Codes(string topvalue)
```

dont know why editor took that datarow off. bracket and datarow.

Comment: That d in the rerurn line is mistake sorry

Comment: and one more mistake i made firstCallingCode should be replaced by topvalue

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass in the return value from the Codes method.

```
ddcodes.datasource = Codes();
ddcodes.databind();
```

You don't need to "get" an enumerable.  The Codes method is already returning one.